# How to stop my set interval after a few tries?

Tags: vue.js, setinterval

I am trying to stop my set interval function to stop after sending the information to my Iframe but clearInterval() isnt actually working.

i ALSO TRIED TO USE

Here's the code:

```js
    <script>
         let interval = null;
         let count = 0;

         interval = setInterval(function(){

           document.getElementById('iframe')
            .contentWindow.postMessage({
              userData: { 
                info1: localStorage.info1,
                info2: localStorage.info2,
                info3: localStorage.info3
                  }}, 
                'http://localhost:8081/list') }, 10000);

          export default {

            name: 'Dashboard',

              components: {
                ToolBar
            },
            methods: {

              connect(){

              clearInterval(interval);
              console.log("CONNECTING!!!!!!!!!");;
              this.$router.push("/aplicativo");

              }

              },
               data () {
              return {
                //
              }

            }, 
          }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have better results by initializing the `setInterval` within your component's `mounted` function, and by storing the interval ID as part of the component:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            this.interval = null;
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.interval = setInterval(...);
    },
    connect() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not giving you the direct answer, its an approach

```
mounted() {
    let tries = 3; // suppose you want to stop after 3 tries
    let interval = setInterval(() => { 
        if (!tries--) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        } else { 
           // TODO: your stuff
        }
    }, 1000); // interval for 1000 milisec
}
```